# Absorbing impact force during collision in a Car racing game

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics-engine

I am making a racing game and I want to impact between the wall and the car to be absorbed to the level where the car travelling at high-speed cant be thrown away in the other direction due to the large force... The video below shows how the car is booted away, and I want to reduce that to the minimum
https://youtu.be/wGtMAXLG4b8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set [PhysicMaterial.bounciness](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PhysicMaterial-bounciness.html) as 0, if you don't want this effect at all. Or change it as you wish.

> How bouncy is the surface? A value of 0 will not bounce. A value of 1
> will bounce without any loss of energy.

So, optimum value can be found with a few gameplay test. If you set it to 0, car won't lose any energy at all, so speed will be same. If it is 0, car's speed will be 0 and all energy will convert to the momentum.

Comment: The physics material bounciness is zero and it still behaves that way in impact collisions

Comment: Try changing value of **Bounce ThresHold** in [Physic Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html). Set it really high and see how this works out for you.

Comment: @Michealmystics In case of **Physic Manager** didn't fix your problem, **HACK IT UNTIL MAKE IT**. You can set [Rigidbody.isKinematic](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) to false when collision happens, then set it to true back.

Comment: do you mean set Rigidbody.isKinematic to true cause the default is false